# Change canvas color on touch 2

Tags: android, colors, android-canvas, ondraw, ontouch

I'm trying to develop an app, the only function of this app is change the color of the canvas when I touch the screen, but I can't get it. here's the code. thanks, I'm learning this and It's kind of difficult to me.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.EventLog.Event;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class Juego extends View implements OnTouchListener {
 Bitmap  bitmap;
    Path    path = new Path();
    Canvas  canvas;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int colorchange=0;

public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);

}
public boolean onTouch (View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
    if(colorchange==0){
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    colorchange=1;
    }else{
    canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
    colorchange=0;
    }
    }
    invalidate();
    break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
}
}
```

Comment: what is your problem - I see some source code and what you're trying to do but not a description of what isn't working/error messages

Comment: the problem is that the app doesn't change the color when I run it, it doesn't appear any error but It doesn't do what I want

Comment: @NickWilde I need help in this app, I don't know why the screen doesn't change the color when I touch it. please I'll thank you so much